# Function Scope issue when declaring an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, scope

This is the code that I currently have, one problem that is happening is I cannot use `test()` because `presets[index].name` and `value` are not visible outside of their function scope, how should I declare my array of objects in the global scope in order for me to be able to access these two variables in other functions?

```
var presets = [];
var index;

function CreatePresetArray(AMib, AVar) {
    var parentpresetStringOID = snmp.getOID(AMib, AVar);
    var presetStringOID = parentpresetStringOID;
    parentpresetStringOID = parentpresetStringOID.substring(0, parentpresetStringOID.length - 2);
    log.error("parentpresetStringOID is " + parentpresetStringOID);

    var presetswitches = {};

    for (var i = 1; i < 41; i++) {
        presets.push(presetswitches);
        try {
            log.error("presetStringOID before getNextVB= " + presetStringOID);
            vb = snmp.getNextVB(presetStringOID);
            presetStringOID = vb.oid;
            log.error("presetStringOID  after getnextVB= " + presetStringOID);

            var presetStringVal = snmp.get(presetStringOID);

            log.error("presetStringVal= " + presetStringVal);

            index = i - 1;

            presets[index].name = presetStringOID;
            presets[index].value = presetStringVal;
            log.error("preset array's OID at position [" + index + "]     is" + presets[index].name + " and the value stored is " + presets[index].value);

            //log.error("presets Array value ["+index+"] =     "+presets[index].configs);

            if (presetStringOID.indexOf(parentpresetStringOID) != 0) {
                break;
            }

        } catch (ie) {
            log.error("couldn't load preset array " + index);
        };
    };
}

CreatePresetArray(presetMib, "presetString");

function test() {
    for (i = 1; i < 41; i++) {
        log.error("test" + presets[index].name + "        " + presets[index].value);
    };
}
test();
```

Comment: Please paste the code you mention

Comment: take your time, indent every code line at least 4 characters ... and it will work

Comment: You can also post a link to jsfiddle.net/ or codepen.io

Comment: Where and how exactly do you call the function `CreatePresetArray`?

Comment: Which means "if you don't call it at all, that would be the problem" :-)

Comment: I did call it in my script i just forgot to add it here in stackoverflow

Comment: Presets are actually global in your code and not in the function scope. Two of the most important things when writing software is defining clear responsibilities for each element of the program and defining the dependencies of each piece of code. What about `return`ing the result from the function instead of relying on global state?

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop in your function `test` iterates over `i` but uses `index` inside the loop. Perhaps you meant to use

```
for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) { // 1 lower as you were using `index = i - 1` before
    log.error("test" + presets[i].name + "        " + presets[i].value);
}
```

---

Re-wrote your code. I don't think I made that much by way of change. If this doesn't clear up your problem, consider: Is the `catch` happening each iteration? Is the problem actually coming from a different method which is only visible here? Also, consider logging the whole `presets` *Array* when debugging to see what it looks like.

```
var presets = [];

function CreatePresetArray(AMib, AVar) {
    var parentPresetOID, presetOID, presetValue, preset, vb, i;
    parentPresetOID = snmp.getOID(AMib, AVar);
    presetOID = parentPresetOID; // initial
    parentPresetOID = parentPresetOID.substring(0, parentPresetOID.length - 2);

    log.error("parentPresetOID is " + parentPresetOID);
    presets = []; // empty array in case not already empty
    for (i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
        try {
            preset = {}; // new object
            // new presetOID
            vb = snmp.getNextVB(presetOID);
            presetOID = vb.oid;
            log.error("presetOID  after getnextVB= " + presetOID);
            // new value
            presetValue = snmp.get(presetOID);
            log.error("presetValue= " + presetValue);
            // append data to object
            preset.name = presetOID;
            preset.value = presetValue;
            // append object to array
            presets.push(preset);
            // more logging
            log.error(
                "preset array's OID at position [" + i + "]" +
                "     is" + presets[i].name + " and " +
                "the value stored is " + presets[i].value
            );
            if (presetOID.indexOf(parentPresetOID) !== 0) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (ie) {
            log.error("couldn't load preset array " + i);
            if (presets.length !== i + 1) { // enter dummy for failed item
                presets.push(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried to use i instead of index, but it still can't see the .name and .value of array presets, because it was only declared in function createpresetArray

Comment: No, it wasn't. You declared it before the function. That should be sufficient, if you call the function `CreatePresetArray` before you call `test()`

Comment: I tried calling createpresetArray before calling test(), when I compile, the error says cannot read property "name" from undefined

Comment: Please try again with my edited code, the error may have been appearing only on the last iteration

Comment: thank you Paul, I tried with your code, but still no luck, it gives the same error as before.

Comment: I am actually still trying to figure out why i declared presetswitches={}; within the function and did a presets.push(presetswitches); I tried to take away these two lines of code, and my code wouldn't compile anymore, the reason why I added them is because I thought I needed to push into the array an object everytime before I set to .name and .value their respective values. but is it really because of that?

Comment: @happy oh.. lol now I've seen that, it looks like each item in the array will point to the same reference anyway.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the help, in the end I just ended up doing presets.push({ name:currentArrayPointer, value:presetStringVal });

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind immediately:

- you could pass the preset array as a argument to test().
- You could put both CreatePresetArray() and test() inside a wrapper function and declare preset array at the top of your wrapper. That would give them both access to the variable.

It's generally considered Bad Form to declare globals if it can be avoided. Pollutes the namespace.

Comment: `presets` is `var`d before the `CreatePresetArray` declaration.

Comment: the thing is from what I was told, I am suppose to create two different functions, the first one which is createpresetArray, and the second one is suppose to be able to refer to the array that I created by giving it an index, this means that both functions shouldn't be wrapped in a wrapper, and I was also told that the second function which refer to the array I created shouldn't take the array as an argument but simply an index.